# Bitcoin Cash Wallet Recovery

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, bitcoin-cash

I just realized that I have an old Electrum wallet with a small amount of Bitcoin. I'd like to claim the Bitcoin Cash, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I do have the original wallet password & seed phrase. I've also transferred the associated Bitcoin to a new address.

According to the [Electrum site](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt), I shouldn't install Electrum Cash on the same computer as Electrum. Unfortunately I don't have another computer to work with. I do have an iPhone & a Trezor, but I haven't figured out how to sweep my Electrum address into one of those devices.

What are my options for recovering the Bitcoin Cash without installing Electrum Cash?

Comment: If you still have the seed of the electrum wallet, you could setup the trezor using that seed, then use it to send the bcash wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy steps :
1.  Start up Electrum where your Bitcoin is.
2.  Save the Wallet Private Key somewhere safe.
3.  Move your Bitcoin to your Trezor or Ledger (you really should have a hardware cold wallet).
4.  Now install ElectronCash from electroncash.org (it's fine on same PC)
5.  Start up ElectronCash & login with *SAME* password as your Electrum.
6.  You'll see the Bitcoin Cash sitting there.
7.  Transfer Bitcoin Cash into Ledger or Trezor (using the Beta Trezor Wallet here : https://beta-wallet.trezor.io/)
8.  You're all set.

Cheers!

Comment: [WARNING: "Electron Cash" will copy all your Electrum wallets to its own directory, and their binaries are anonymous:](https://twitter.com/electrumwallet/status/891935330235973633)

Answer (score 1):

Just did it. Easy Pezzy work.
Copy the Seed/secret key from my electrum (original BTC) wallet and used it in "I already have a seed" option in electrum cash wallet. It will login and show you your remaining Bitcoin Cash.

Ps: I have Electrum and Electrum Cash wallets installed in the same PC. Didnt have any problem during transfer.
I did transfer my original BTC to another wallet for safety. But i doubt i needed to do that coz i doubt any reply problem will occur since they are separate blockchains.